# Very slow RedHawk component builds

Tags: redhawksdr

We have some components that build 15+ object files before linking them.  We find that if we modify a .h file used by many or all, that builds are VERY slow.  Some of our components take over an hour to build.  It appears that RedHawk issues a make -j or a make -j with a large number, so that we have 15+ compiles running simultaneously and this overwhelms even 4 GB of RAM and results in excessive swapping and VERY slow execution (the entire CPU is nearly locked up, other windows are also dead until it completes).  If we use a simple make from shell in the component it completes in 5 min.  Is there a way to change RH to issue a simple make or make with an adjustable number of max processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to how the IDE invokes the build you can check the build console.  I'm pretty sure it either calls the top level build.sh or the build.sh within your implementation's folder.  In either case you can modify that file to perform the build however you'd like.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed